# How to convert numbers into indicative string

Tags: objective-c, numbers, formatter

I just want to know how can I can convert the numbers 1, 2 or 3 into First, second or Third ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: osx ? You can nearly do this without single line of code

Comment: The word you are looking for is ordinal. That is what "first" "second" "third" ... are

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
- (NSString *)getOrdinalTextFor:(NSInteger)number {

     NSNumber *numberValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:number];
     NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterOrdinalStyle];

     return [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:numberValue];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this one may be it helps you,

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle];
    NSString* numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 3]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numberString);
```

Comment: if we give 123 then it'l come like this one hundred twenty-three.

Comment: he want First Second Third.

Comment: program it! that is the solution!

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classRuleBasedNumberFormat.html)Download Formatter kit from [GitHub](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit)

```
TTTOrdinalNumberFormatter *ordinalNumberFormatter = [[TTTOrdinalNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[ordinalNumberFormatter setGrammaticalGender:TTTOrdinalNumberFormatterMaleGender];
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:2];
NSString *str = [ordinalNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Read up this link, its very helpful: [Number Formatting](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classRuleBasedNumberFormat.html)